# On which DTH operator can I get Animax channel in India?

Tags: resources, india

I have Tata Sky at my place right now, but there is no Animax channel in any of the packs which they are currently offering. 
So which DTH operators are currently telecasting Animax in India?

Comment: You can get animax in Hathway, Digi cable, Siti cable etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to update this answer that Tata Sky has taken up Animax back into its Kids channel package at a cost of 65 Rupees a month.

I think this is a very useful information for all Anime fans in India. I do hope this information will give some boost to the Anime scene in India.

Answer (score 4):

All DTH providers in India have delisted Animax, as the channel couldn't pay carriage fees.

But you can watch it on cable on

- Hathway Channel 324
- Fastway Channel 381
- DigiCable Channel 278
- Kerala Vision Digital TV Channel 158