# Which content providers show anime in India?

Tags: resources, india

Other than [SonyLiv](https://www.sonyliv.com/details/live/5495190673001/Animax-HD---LIVE-CHANNEL), which content providers have Anime in India ?

Repeating question: [On which DTH operator can I get Animax channel in India?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20995/on-which-dth-operator-can-i-get-animax-channel-in-india)?